# Angular 8 : result fetched from reducer using ngRx/store is not updating the UI in async (html)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ngrx-store, redux-observable

```
My issue is similar to <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123304/angular-using-ngrx-store-and-pipe-async-not-get-update-in-the-dom>.
```

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Ingredient } from '../shared/ingredient.model';
import { ShoppingListService } from './shopping-list.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-list',
  templateUrl: './shopping-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-list.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ingredients: Observable<{ ingredients: Ingredient[] }>;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private slService: ShoppingListService,
    private store: Store<{ shoppingList: { ingredients: Ingredient[] } }>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ingredients = this.store.select('shoppingList');
  }

  onEditItem(index: number) {
    this.slService.startedEditing.next(index);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <app-shopping-edit></app-shopping-edit>
    <hr>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <a
        class="list-group-item"
        style="cursor: pointer"
        *ngFor="let ingredient of (ingredients | async).ingredients; let i = index"
        (click)="onEditItem(i)"
      >
        {{ ingredient.name }} ({{ ingredient.amount }})
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


{
  "name": "ng-complete-guide-update",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"core-js": "^3.1.2",
"firebase": "^7.12.0",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.25",
"@angular/cli": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

The async in html fails with error : ingredients of undefined.
If i try to subscribe in ngOninit,to set the ingredients a property in a class.it still fails with undefined in subscription.

i have upgraded all the dependencies.The author of the tutorial is not getting this issue though when i try ,it fails to fetch set data from reducers to UI though i can see the values in debug mode.

When i searched for an answer,all i get is issue with zone.As i am new to this not sure how to resolve.

https://github.com/DineshNO/ng4-complete-guide.git

Comment: let ingredient of (ingredients | async)?.ingredients..?

Comment: @MikeOne export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ingredients: Observable<{ ingredients: Ingredient[] }>;   -- naming is bad but just wanted to replicate as such in course repo

Comment: I meant, you could try to add the safe operator (object?.key). The question mark.

Comment: @MikeOne, Thanks for quick response.But the issue for me is not the undefined but fetching the values to html.Why i am not able to transfer data to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   {
  "name": "ng4-complete-guide",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^4.0.3",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^4.0.3",
    "@ngrx/store": "^4.0.3",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "firebase": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.27",
    "acorn": "^7.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "^3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

My new package json with which async works.
Will upgrade to Angualar 8 along with others later.
thanks.